# How to display always 5 words (tags) from a sentence in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

After running a query, I get an array of results (articles) where each of them has their properties like `id`, `name` and `tags`.

This is the code where I display those values:

```
    @foreach ( $results['matches'] as $doc => $docinfo )
    ...
    {{$docinfo['attrs']['s_tags']}}
    @endforeach
```

But the problem is that some of articles have a long list of tags, for example:

```
"s_tags" => "Tech, geben, rasant, Wechsel, Pakete, Kunden, Details, Intel, Microsoft, Angebote, App, Web"
```

How can I assure that maximum 5 tags are displayed. So in this case it would be:

```
"Tech, geben, rasant, Wechsel, Pakete"
```

and of course, if there are articles with the number of tags less than 5, I want to display them all.

Comment: You can collect just 5 tags with query. Is it possible with your case ?

Comment: It is not possible. I need to extract 5 words from a sentence (simple string), not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{ collect(explode(', ', $docinfo['attrs']['s_tags']))->take(5)->implode(', ') }}
```

- Explode the string on `,` to turn it into an array
- Turn it into a collection with `collect` to get a fluent readable api
- Take at most 5 elements
- Implode it on `,` to get your comma delimited list back

Comment: It still displays all the tags. But the tag is a sentence where each tag is separated by comma. So `take(5)` doesn't work in this case.

Comment: What do you mean a sentence? Do you mean a string? Explode splits the string at each comma meaning from `'a, b, c, d'` you would get `['a', 'd', 'c', 'd']`.

Comment: Yes, a string.  Look at my post where I've showed an example of `s_tags`. I am trying your solution, but it doesn't work :( .

Comment: My answer is exploding on `, ` (notice the space) because of the space in your example `Tech, geben...`. Perhaps remove the space. i.e. `explode(`,`, ...`.

Answer (score 1):

simple use `implode` and `explode` and `array_slice()`

```
{{ implode(', ',array_slice(explode(',',$docinfo['attrs']['s_tags']),0,5)) }}
```

**Implode :** Break the array into string

**Explode :** Break the string into array

**Array_slice :** Get the particular slice of element from array with limits

Comment: Like the solution from @Ben Swinburne ... There is no change at all :/

Comment: Both solutions works fine. I made a mistake because I was implementing this on wrong place. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_slice()` like this:

I don't know about your tag array. let it be `$tag`.

```
$five = array_slice($tag, 0, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

TRy this it will help from query side

```
DB::table('articles')->chunk(5, function($results)
{
    foreach ($results['matches'] as $doc => $docinfo)
    {
         {{$docinfo['attrs']['s_tags']}}
    }
});
```

Comment: I use Sphinx search (https://github.com/sngrl/sphinxsearch) - `$results = $cl->search('@*' . $name, 'spots');`